# How i can hide and show column and value of row?

Tags: javascript, html

I've some problem with a table, about hiding and showing a specific column and value on it,that's the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables 
    var rigaZona, colonnaZona;
    colonnaZona = document.getElementById("colonnaZona");
    rigaZona = document.getElementById("rigaZona");
    rigaZona.style.display='blocked';
    colonnaZona.style.display='blocked';
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="display:none;">head1</th>
    <th>head2</th>
    <th style="width: 65%;">head3</th>
    <th>head4</th>
    <th>head5</th>
    <th id="colonnaZona" style="display:none;">head6</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td style="display:none">miao</td>
    <td>bau</td>
    <td>roar</td>
    <td>cip</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td id="rigaZona" style="display:none">africa</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Something appear, but not what I'm expecting, I want to set the rigaZona and colonnaZona as visible on change of the select, any solution?

Comment: what exactly are you trying, you only have those variables, which you never assign to the `<th>` or `<td>` with the corrosponding id's.

Comment: yeah sorry, i forgot to paste the code, i edited now, before u can say something about, i've to say that if i replace the (' ') with ('blocked') nothing change

Comment: `display()` such a function not exist. `style.display="none";` to hide and `style.display="block"` to show.

Comment: `style.display` is a property, not a function. It's because `display(value)` don't work.

Comment: i just wrote it in parenthesis, on page the code is style.display, dont worry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate your select list in corresponding to showing and hiding specific columns in table. It is better to give `id /`class`in each`th`and`td` the same with value in select class. Try this one:

selecting will change table appearance:

```js
//getting select list value
var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#sels option"));
    arr.forEach(function(v,i){
      arr[i] = v.value;
    })

function arrShow(list, cl) {
  list.forEach(function(el) {
    var t = document.getElementsByClassName(el);    
    if (el === cl) {
      //just hard coded it since i know only two elements th and td
      t[0].style.display = 'block';
      t[1].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      t[0].style.display = 'none';
      t[1].style.display = 'none';
    } 
  })
}

arrShow(arr, "c2");

function myFunction(s) {
  arrShow(arr,s);
}
```

```css
table td {
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<select id="sels" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
  <option value="c1">c1</option>
  <option value="c2" selected>c2</option>
  <option value="c6">c6</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th class="c1">head1</th>
    <th class="c2">head2</th>
    <th class="c3" style="width: 65%;">head3</th>
    <th class="c4">head4</th>
    <th class="c5">head5</th>
    <th class="c6">head6</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="c1">miao</td>
    <td class="c2">bau</td>
    <td class="c3">roar</td>
    <td class="c4">cip</td>
    <td class="c5">asd</td>
    <td class="c6">africa</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting the DOM elements, to change style attributes you have to use .style property, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("colonnaZona").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("rigaZona").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happen,it show the first row value, then nothing if i change the value again

Comment: that's because you only specify the element to become visible when the select's option is changed. to hide/display specific thing you'll need more than this little piece of code.

Comment: i've to hide the entire column, not only a specific value...it's worth to hide even row ?

Answer (score 0):

[Display](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_style_display.asp) is a property, not a function. To change display style, use :

```
 rigaZona.style.display = 'none';
```

Also, display has options like *block*, *none*, *inline-block*, etc. but there is no such option as `""`

Comment: `.display = ''` === `.display = "inline"` 
that is from what i get (here)[http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_display.as]}

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var colonnaZona = document.getElementById("colonnaZona");
    var rigaZona = document.getElementById("rigaZona");

    colonnaZona.classList.add('visible-cell');
    rigaZona.classList.add('visible-cell');
}
```

If you want to toggle the visibility of the elements use `element.classList.toggle('visible-cell')` instead.

And then somewhere in your stylesheets

```
.visible-cell {
    display: table-cell !important;
}
```

Comment: i've to change something on table or row too?

Comment: No need to touch the HTML but the code was indeed not working, fixed now